# React. List -> ListItem click and send params

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Cant understand how i can create click by item in List and sent params. For example if i using this code

```
    <List>
         {filesList ? (
           filesList.map((item, index) => (
            <ListItem key={index} button onClick={this.setCurrentUrl(index)}>
               <ListItemIcon>
                   <InsertDriveFile/>
               </ListItemIcon>
               <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
            </ListItem>
        ))
    ) : (
            <ListItem>There are no attachement files</ListItem>)}
            <ListItem/>
      </List>
```

method `setCurrentUrl`:

```
setCurrentUrl(index) {
        console.log(index);
    }
```

i will have output all items in the console when my page is loaded. Why? But if i make something like this:

```
<ListItem key={index} button onClick={this.setCurrentUrl} value={index}>
```

and

```
setCurrentUrl(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
```

then `console.log(event);` will be call only when i click on item in the list. But in this way i dont know how send params to `setCurrentUrl`

Comment: You can do something like : ```onClick={() => this.setCurrentUrl(index)}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it happens because you are calling the function. The function will execute immediately after the component is rendered .

```
 <ListItem key={index} button onClick={this.setCurrentUrl(index)}>
```

Instead what you should have done is

```
<ListItem key={index} button onClick={() => this.setCurrentUrl(index)}>
```

What this will do is , it will assign the function to the **onClick** handler and will be invoked only when you click the button.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are using

```
 <ListItem key={index} button onClick={this.setCurrentUrl(index)}>
```

it is problematic as the function setCurrentUrl will be called as soon as the component is rendered. To make a call to function only when onClick event is triggered, you need to make use of callbacks.

```
<ListItem key={index} button onClick={() => this.setCurrentUrl(index)}>
```

Using callback will not call the function while the component is being rendered and would only call the function when the onClick event is triggered.